# Запятыми не выделяются обороты с союзом как, если...?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

[Сравнительные обороты в русском языке](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)

> Как навязчивая мелодия кружила меня эта мысль.

Ставить... не ставить... оставить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как навязчивая мелОдия // кружила меня эта мысль.**

Оборот не обособляется, на него падает логическое ударение. Именно поэтому применена инверсия и оборот вынесен в начале предложения.

**Оборот входит в состав простого предложения.** Здесь присутствует небольшая пауза, но она обозначает перелом интонации, характерный для любого простого предложения: тема — рема, обстоятельственный оборот — остальная часть предложения.

Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp1474.

Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:

1) если на первый план выступает **значение обстоятельства образа действия** (обороты с как можно заменить в этих случаях формой творительного падежа существительного или наречием): **Как зарницы в небе они запылали, как огненный дождь с неба упали;**

**Примечание:** Замена в приведенном предложении  неактуальна, важно обстоятельственное значение.